# How do I navigate this list containing nested dictionaries?

Tags: python

From this list below I want to either convert it into a dictionary or call "name" as a dictionary type e.g list["name"]

How do I do this?

```
list = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_proxyTo","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"_new","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"_old","type":"address"}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

- It depends which name you want to call

#### example:

```
false = False
lis = '[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_proxyTo","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"_new","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"_old","type":"address"}]}]'
lis = eval(lis)
print(lis[0]["inputs"][0]["name"])
print(lis[1]["inputs"][0]["name"])
print(lis[1]["inputs"][1]["name"])
```

#### result:

```
_proxyTo
_new
_old
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get the error "string indices must be integers" when I try and use your method however :(

Comment: @axell2017 I fix some quote errors in the question's `list`, please double check the `list` in the code you run and the `list` in the question are the same or not.

Comment: I apologize I thought all lists were treated as strings. I have edited the list code to a more accurate example

Comment: @axell2017 I add a right quote `}` and a `]` to make the `list` make sense.

Comment: You would want to use ```ast.literal_eval```

Comment: @Sujay I try to use `ast.literal_eval`, but his `list` has a lowercase `false` in it, which can't be handled by `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @Sujay If use eval, you can add a variable `false = False` to get over it.